# SQL Agent Job to run .bat with gsutil rsync

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, rsync, gsutil, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a scheduled SQL Agent Job that executes a `.bat` file with a `gsutil rsync` command to synchronize a local folder with a Google Cloud Bucket. The task runs without an error, but does not finish or actually perform the rsync command.

I can however manually run the .bat file with success as the root user, as I have a key handshake with the GCP service account. I can also successfully execute other non-gsutil `.bat` files from the SQL Agent Job, as I have created credentials and proxy to run as the root user

The `.bat` file looks like this :

```
gsutil rsync -r G:\MyBackupFolder gs://my-coldline-storage-bucket
```

and I am running the SQL Agent step as type **Operating system (CmdExec)**

Comment: if you are able to run from command prompt successfully ,you can change sql agent  step to use cmdexec `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-cmdexec-job-step`

Comment: The question clearly states that I am already using step type CmdExec, I have tried powershell also

Comment: Can you collect logs from the gsutil command to see if it is actually being executed?  If you can do that, you can run gsutil -D rsync -r ... to get a better picture of what is going on.